# Moment.js get the week number based on a specific day (also past years)

Tags: javascript, momentjs, week-number

How could I get from moment JS the week number from a date in the past only from a moment formatted object from a day selected?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var weeknumber = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
    console.log(weeknumber);
  });
```

According momentjs docs:

> Because different locales define week of year numbering differently,
>   Moment.js added moment#week to get/set the localized week of the year.
>
> The week of the year varies depending on which day is the first day of
>   the week (Sunday, Monday, etc), and which week is the first week of
>   the year.
>
> For example, in the United States, Sunday is the first day of the
>   week. The week with January 1st in it is the first week of the year.

So, if you are having problems getting the right week number use .isoWeek()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var weeknumber = moment("11-26-2016", "MMDDYYYY").isoWeek();
  alert(weeknumber);
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yz2oe92a/3/)

Comment: Be careful with this as moment("12/31/2015", "MM/DD/YYYY").week() will return 1 as the week.  You may also want to look at moment().isoWeek()

Comment: for 29 november 2016 return 47 as the week. But real is 48.

Comment: Answer improved @mathewsun

Comment: Just to be clear, if you use any of the solutions given above _(`moment().format('w')`,  `moment().week()`, `moment().isoWeek()`, etc.)_ you should be aware that they will give you the exact week number. 

So for example the date `moment('2018-12-31').format('w')` will return `1`, because is the Monday in the first week of 2019. Is the last day of 2018, but is not in a week of 2018.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use `format()`

**Examples:**

```
moment().format('w') // as .week() like '1'
moment().format('W') // as .isoWeek() like '1'
moment().format('ww') // as .week() (2 digits) like '01'
moment().format('WW') // as .isoWeek() (2 digits) like '01'
```

*ISO Week date: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date*

**More info:** https://momentjs.com/docs/#week-year-week-and-weekday-tokens

Comment: AND ALSO `GGGG` or `GG` gives the iso year corresponding to that week

Comment: Example: note that today (`Monday 12/30/19`) is actually part of ISO Week 1 of 2020 and therefore if you use `WW yyyy` and not `WW GGGG` you'll get `1 2019` instead of `1 2020`

Comment: Can use with standart ISO format for Year of Week: `moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY").format("GGGG-[W]WW-E")`

Answer (score 3):

to get week number by current date

```
moment(moment().toDate(), "MM-DD-YYYY").isoWeek()
```

Comment: `moment().toDate()` returns a *Date* object as if by `new Date()`. When a *Date* instance is passed to *moment*, the format string is ignored (because it's irrelevant). `moment(new Date())` is identical to `moment()`, so the above should be simply `moment().isoWeek()`.  ;-)

Answer (score -3):

`moment().format("d")` gives you the week number, between 0 and 6, where 0 represents Sunday and 6 represents Saturday