# MomentJS get weekNumber with variable first day of week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get the weeknumer of a date, but I want it to work with a variable first day of the week. A user is able to set the first day of the week. I couldn't find a javascript solution, so I tried moment. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to set the first day of the week. E.g. Sunday for US, Monday for the EU, but it would be nice if it could be any other day as well.

Comment: Kindly post a code snippet to work on.

Comment: A snippet of what? The initialisation of a moment object??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js get the week number based on a specific day (also past years)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953551/moment-js-get-the-week-number-based-on-a-specific-day-also-past-years)

Comment: @lumio unfortunately it isn't. In the your link it is not possible to set the first day of the week.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the first day of the week". You mean you want to change if Sunday or Monday is the first day? Or like actually setting a date

Comment: @lumio Indeed change it to sunday of monday. Athough it would be nice if it could be any other day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moment supports [i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/), you can [change locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) or [change locales locally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) and update first day of the week according locale rules. Then you can use [`week()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) that:

> Gets or sets the week of the year.
>
> Because different locales define week of year numbering differently, Moment.js added `moment#week` to get/set the localized week of the year.
>
> The week of the year varies depending on which day is the first day of the week (Sunday, Monday, etc), and which week is the first week of the year.

Here a example showing how the same day (e.g. `2017-08-13`) has different week value using different locales:

```js
moment.locale('en');
var now2 = moment('2017-08-13');
console.log( now2.week() ); // 33

moment.locale('it');
var now1 = moment('2017-08-13');
console.log( now1.week() ); // 32
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you don't want to change moment locale, you can simply customize the first day of the week (for the current locale) using `updateLocale` method, just change the value of `dow` (day of week) key (and `doy` key too, if needed) of the `week` object. See [Customize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) section of the docs to get more info about locale customization.

Here a live example:

```js
var now1 = moment('2017-08-13');
console.log( now1.week() ); // 33

moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: {
    dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
  }
});

var now2 = moment('2017-08-13');
console.log( now2.week() ); // 32
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```